# Can not turn off wordpress update emails

Tags: wordpress, email, notifications

I am currently receiving 2 e-mails a day asking me to update a Wordpress multisite I once worked on...and I am starting to get desperate!

Things I have tried: 
I have changed my email adress both for the admin user and in the general settings. 
I have tried adding the following to the functions.php file:

```
apply_filters( 'auto_core_update_send_email', false);

add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false');

apply_filters( 'send_core_update_notification_email', false);
```

..without any luck.

An obvious solution would be to just update :), but I am hoping to solve this problem once and for all since I am no longer taking this kind of work and have lots of other sites I have worked on in the past.

Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You almost have the correct answer. Change apply_filters to add_filter. Also you need to use '__return_false' which is a hook that just returns false. Using false directly won't do anything. Here's the complete version:

```
// This stops emails being sent to you after an automatic update.
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );

// This stops emails being sent to you to notify you of a new core update.
add_filter( 'send_core_update_notification_email', '__return_false' );
```